# How to inject different client for retrofit when testing?

Tags: android, retrofit, android-testing, dagger

Is there any way to change the way to inject, with Dagger, the Retrofit module with different client to the RestAdapter on instrumentation tests?

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public APIService getAPIService() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.HOST)
            .build();
    return restAdapter.create(APIService.class);
}
```

But, I want to set a new client when executing instrumentation tests.

```
@Provides
@Singleton
public APIService getAPIService() {
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.HOST)
            .setClient(new MockClient())
            .build();
    return restAdapter.create(APIService.class);
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did this in my project. You can find the sample [here](https://github.com/sliskiCode/Robust-unit-testing-in-Android/tree/master). App code is written in Kotlin and uses Dagger 2. Master branch contains Java code and Dagger 1 implementation. I hope this will help :)

Comment: Link fixed but answer is deprecated. You can achieve it using grade flavours.